# MaterializeCSS Modal Not Opening

Tags: javascript, materialize

This is my HTML code for Modal:

```
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <h4>Modal Header</h4>
    <p>A bunch of text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#!" class="modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is how I am referencing it in JS:

```
function aFunction() {
    var elem = document.querySelector('.modal');
    var instance = M.Modal.getInstance(elem);
    instance.open();
}
```

I am calling the function on button click but the modal doesn't show up. The only change I notice is that scrollbars on the right disappear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which version are you using?

This is how it is done in example [the docs](https://materializecss.com/modals.html) for v1.0.0:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
  var instances = M.Modal.init(elems);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Modal Trigger -->
<button data-target="modal1" class="btn modal-trigger">Open the modal</button>

<button class="btn">Do something else</button>

<!-- Modal Structure -->
<div id="modal1" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <h4>Modal Header</h4>
    <p>A bunch of text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#!" class="modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or if you want to open it programatically (via your own functions), you need to init the modal first.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
  var instances = M.Modal.init(elems);
  
  var singleModalElem = document.querySelector('#modal1');
  var instance = M.Modal.getInstance(singleModalElem);
  const modalbtn = document.querySelector('#open')
  modalbtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    instance.open();
    // Do other stuff
  })
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<!-- Modal Structure -->
<div id="modal1" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <h4>Modal Header</h4>
    <p>A bunch of text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#!" class="modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="open">Open a single modal</button>
```

Comment: I am using the latest version. I want to open modal on a specific button click not when DOM is loaded. The button I have is calling the function `aFunction()`

Comment: I'm confused. Does this answer not `open modal on a specific button click`?

Comment: Button in your code is directly opening the modal which is not what I want. As said earlier, on button click, `aFunction()` is getting called, through which I want to open modal.

Comment: The function I have is also executing other statements so I cannot open the modal the default way via anchor tag.

Comment: Ok. It looks like you forgot to init your modal before trying to get the instance. Check the edit.